# XCode 5 Cannot run on selected device

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Cocos2d-x v3 beta, XCode 5.0.2 on 10.9

I have been running V3 Alpha 0 and things are fine.

I downloaded V3 Beta.

I used create_project.py to create a new application

If I try and run this application it works in the simulator

I import all of my source and resources. My app compiles and I get "XCode 5 cannot run on selected device " I have gotten this before in the past and always was solvable.

Here is what I have tried.

1. Build -> Clean
2. Removed Derived Data.
3. Reset all iOS Simulators.
4. Opened cocos2d_libs and changed all 'ios' to Deployment Target = iso7 and rebuilt everything.
5. using LLVm 5 and this is set

Still no luck.

Comment: What error you are seeing?

Comment: XCode Cannot Run Using The Selected Device

Comment: Could you please make sure that you have closed Xcode 5 and simulator when you cleared /Users/your_usr_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/. Also,  remove Info.plist from the target (but, don't remove the file itself).

Comment: I did all of that and nada. Even reset every simulator

Comment: Sorry for many questions... Could you please make sure your executable file (Project->Info->Executable file) pointing to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.

Comment: So it has something to do with the info.plist as I have everything working but for some reason dropping in the old info plist throws all these errors I am seeing. Now to go item by item in it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get this error when

- the selected device is not set up for development
- the selected device does not support or does not run the targeted iOS version

In your case I suspect the device doesn't run iOS 7. Upgrade the device OS if possible, or select an earlier iOS deployment target.